# How to perform a correct regexp to target links (nginx)

Tags: nginx

I want to perform a few rewrites:

this actually works:

```
rewrite ^/includes/(.*) /wordpress/wp-includes/$1?putyo_happybits=administrator last;
```

and I get this: http://everhide.wordpress.dev/includes/css/dashicons.min.css?ver=4.8.2 (wp-includes are changed to includes)

I also want to do the same for uploads:

```
rewrite ^/files/(.*) http:/everhide.wordpress.dev/content/uploads/$1?putyo_happybits=administrator last;
```

Can not wrap my head around why this does not work.

Some plugin suggests me this: `rewrite ^/files/(.*) /wordpress/http:/everhide.wordpress.dev/content/uploads/$1?putyo_happybits=administrator last;` but this does not look good either.

Comment: Looks like an external redirect. Do you really want it?

Comment: Now it should be an internal thing, something like this:  rewrite ^/files/(.*) /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/$1?putyo_happybits=administrator last; but this does not work